# Error VB. NET "the ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Lot of similar question here. Already checked each of it, the thing is each question has a different scenario not same as mine.

Here's my code

```
Module Module1
Public connection As New SqlConnection
Public Sub connectserver()

    Dim streamreader As New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\asd.txt")
    Dim server As String = streamreader.ReadLine
    Dim database As String = streamreader.ReadLine

    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.ConnectionString = "Database = " & database & ";Server = " & server & ";Trusted_Connection = True;"
            connection.Open()
        End If
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
End Module
```

After executing it. Error shows "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.". I've already tried the things that I know to fix this base on the similar question but same error show. Thanks for helping.

Comment: The exception does not show *after* executing that - it will stop *on* the line that throws it.  Remove the Try/Catch to find out where.  That is also set up to use the `connection` once only.  The next time you try to connect it will throw an NRE.  Move the SqlConnection declaration inside the method.

Comment: The sqlconnection declaration is for public use. I'm using it in other forms.

Comment: Since you 'Dispose' of the connection in that method, you **must** create a new one each time.  Move the connection variable inside the method and make it a Function returning the new connection.

Comment: fixed it. I don't have to dispose the connection in this particular method. I just have to dispose it each time I run the query. Thanks for your help

Comment: @newbie - If you dispose it each time you run the query, you will have to create a new on each time anyway.  It is not best practice to create a connection globally this way.  You will not save anything by doing so.  It is better to declare the connection each time you need to run a query.  As Plutonix stated, make this a Function that returns a SqlConnection instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.ConnectionString = "Database=" & database & ";Data Source=" & server & ";Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

> try using this line in your code.

Comment: Or prepare your connection string with this format. "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"

Answer (score 0):

call `connectserver()` in main function without any extra parameter setting in `connection.ConnectionString` variable.